# Collecting Google Slides Shapes into a Group Using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, shapes, group, google-slides

I have a Google Apps Script that generates 15 to 20 ellipses in specific places on a slide. I have not been able to find how to collect the generated ellipses into a group programmatically. Any insight would be most appreciated.

I have researched the Google Apps Script documentation but have not been able to find a workable solution.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function createColorCodeLabelsSlide() {
  var objSheetFile = retrieveFileObject(strSheetsFileName);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(objSheetFile);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(strTargetSheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var myPres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var newSlide = myPres.appendSlide();

  for (var i=1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var colorCode = data[i][11];
    var myNewShape = newSlide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.ELLIPSE,data[i][3],data[i][2],16,16);
    myNewShape
      .getText()
      .setText(colorCode);
    myNewShape
      .getText()
      .getTextStyle()
      .setFontFamily("Arial")
      .setFontSize(12);
    myNewShape
      .getText()
      .getParagraphStyle()
      .setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    myNewShape
      .getFill()
      .setSolidFill(255,255,255);
  }
}
```

Comment: About `I have a Google Apps Script that generates 15 to 20 ellipses in specific places on a slide.`, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Current script has been added. It references data in a sheet for some of the shape parameters.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing your current script. From your script, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Works perfectly! Obvious in hindsight, but I need to become more proficient in thinking in terms of arrays. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to group the inserted shapes using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about modifying your script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function createColorCodeLabelsSlide() {
  var objSheetFile = retrieveFileObject(strSheetsFileName);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(objSheetFile);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(strTargetSheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var myPres = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var newSlide = myPres.appendSlide();
  var shapes = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var colorCode = data[i][11];
    var myNewShape = newSlide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.ELLIPSE, data[i][3], data[i][2], 16, 16);
    myNewShape.getText().setText(colorCode);
    myNewShape.getText().getTextStyle().setFontFamily("Arial").setFontSize(12);
    myNewShape.getText().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    myNewShape.getFill().setSolidFill(255, 255, 255);
    shapes.push(myNewShape);
  }
  newSlide.group(shapes);
}
```

- When this script is run, all created shapes `myNewShape` are grouped.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your showing script works without any errors. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [group(pageElements)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#group(PageElement))